# Unable to add text from UITextField to an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, uitextfield, gettext

Currently I have a custom view table cell and a text field just above it. I want to get the text from the `UItextfield` and put that into an `NSMutableArray`.

Pseudocode:

```
String text = _textfield.text;
[array addObject:text];
NSLog{array}
```

In my header file I have created the textfield and the array.

I currently receive the error : `'CustomTableView:[340:11303] array: (null)'` when I NSLog.

I am not to sure why the text from the textfield is not getting added to the array. If any one is able to help it will be greatly appreciated.

**Note** - My textfield is above the custom cell not in it. I have even tried just adding a string to the array directly and logging it and I get the same error. So I would assume that this is something to do with the array.

Comment: Did you check the the textField.text is nil or not? Can you post some code? May be you didn't create the array

Comment: your nsmutablearray is not initialized. initialize it before adding the textfield's string

Comment: Did you use Interface Builder to add the textfield, if so, is it linked to `_textField` through an `IBOutlet` in your header file?

Comment: Samfisher you are right. I didn't initialise the variable. I assumed the addobject method did that. Obviously I assumed wrong. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you initialize your Array.take a MutableArray and initialize it.

```
       NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you have declared the textfield and the array in your header file...

Have you initialised the variable `array`?

e.g.

`array = [NSMutableArray new];`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not actually creating the array. In Objective C, you do not create things in header file, you declare them. The implementation files(.m files) do all the work.

Try this:

```
NSString *text = _textfield.text;
array = @[text]
NSLog( @"%@", array );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should print your array,

```
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if your a newbie to ios.Go through the objective-c and Read the apple documentation carefully.

```
 NSString * text = self.textfield.text;
 NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [array addObject:text];
  NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this is what worked...

I have taken one textfield inside tableviewcell. I am creating textfields based on dynamic data. My requirement is , I need to get textfields text which are created dynamically.

For getting text in another method

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableViewObj indexPathForCell:customCell];
    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        [arrayPhoneNumbers addObject:customCell.textFieldObj.text];
        NSLog(@"array is :%@",arrayPhoneNumbers);
    }
    else if(indexPath.row==1)
    {
        [arrayPhoneNumbers addObject:customCell.textFieldObj.text];
        NSLog(@"array is :%@",arrayPhoneNumbers);

    }
    else if(indexPath.row==2)
    {
        [arrayPhoneNumbers addObject:customCell.textFieldObj.text];
        NSLog(@"array is :%@",arrayPhoneNumbers);
    }
```

Like this I have added textfield text to array. Let me know if you have any doubts.