# Access text values from dynamically created UITextFields. iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am creating `UITextField` 's in my view based on the count of an `NSArray`.

I want to know how I can access the text values based on the tag of the `UITextField` in my `NSArray`.

So after I add the below `UITextField` 's to my view how would I write code to retrieve .text values for myTextfield0, myTextfield1 and myTextfield2 respectively?

Example:

```
NSString *textFeildTextString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myTextfield1.text];
```

Actual Code:

```
self.textFieldArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three",nil];

NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (int i=0; i<[self.textFieldArray count]; i++) {

    UIView *spacerView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
    UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60*i+150, 280, 45)];
    myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    myTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
    myTextField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Answer", nil);
    myTextField.inputAccessoryView = [super createInputToolbar];
    myTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TextFieldBg"];
    myTextField.textColor = [UIColor appTextColorGrey];
    [myTextField setLeftView: spacerView1];
    myTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    myTextField.delegate = self;
    myTextField.tag = 200+i;
    [myDict setObject:myTextField forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myTextfield%d", i]];
    [self.view addSubview:myTextField];
}

NSLog(@"Dict: %@",myDict);
```

The NSlog of my UITexfields

```
2014-10-31 11:58:32.715 [51992:13536821] Dict: {
myTextfield0 = "<UITextField: 0x7faea14f8430; frame = (20 150; 280 45); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 200; layer = <CALayer: 0x7faea14f82d0>>";
myTextfield1 = "<UITextField: 0x7faea14fae70; frame = (20 210; 280 45); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 201; layer = <CALayer: 0x7faea14faca0>>";
myTextfield2 = "<UITextField: 0x7faea16dce30; frame = (20 270; 280 45); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 202; layer = <CALayer: 0x7faea16d19c0>>";
```

}

Comment: You are using a dictionary, not an array, which is a good approach.

Comment: You can enumerate through your myDict for textField and get the value. That should be simpler. right..

Comment: I have answered here..may be helpful for someone.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958613/unable-to-add-text-from-uitextfield-to-an-array/31469632#31469632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<[self.textFieldArray count]; i++) {
    UITextField *txt  = (UITextField *)[myDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myTextfield%d", i]];
    NSLog(@"Text %@",txt.text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access them either by their tag :

```
UITextField *textField= (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:200]; // Your first text field (201 your second etc..)
NSString *text = textField.text;
```

Or access them directly via your dictionary as you already know the key for each one of them:

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[myDict objectForKey:@"myTextField0"];
```

Note that in order for the dictionary to stay around declare a strong property member in your class and assign it to the created local dictionary (otherwise it will be lost by ARC) so at the end of the method you will have something like:

```
self.myDict = myDict;
```